# How to add context bound TypeTags to types that take type parameters?

Tags: scala

Given a class:

```
class MyClass[A, B[A] <: SomeClass[A]](...) { ... }
```

I'd like to add type tags to both A and B[A].

However,

```
class MyClass[A: TypeTag, B[A] <: SomeClass[A]: TypeTag]
```

complains about B taking type parameters. Adding an implicit TypeTag[B[A]] instead seem to work, but I need it context bound for some manifest conversions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case there is only `B[A]` and there is no `B[OtherClass]` or `B[_]` in the signature of class `MyClass` you could use `B` instead of `B[A]`:

```
class MyClass[A: TypeTag, B <: SomeClass[A]: TypeTag](sc: B, e: A)
new MyClass(new SomeClass[String], "a")
// MyClass[String,SomeClass[String]] = MyClass@790e79dc
```

Here is an ugly solution with `B[A]`, but I guess you should just use implicit parameters:

```
class MyClass[A: TypeTag,
              B[A] <: SomeClass[A]: ({type l[M[_]] = TypeTag[M[A]]})#l ](sc: B[A], e: A)
```

Comment: Sadly, the type B[A] is needed inside MyClass as a type for another class that demands the [A], so I can't do without it.

Comment: @Aeris130: See update, but you should just use an implicit parameter.